# Sending multiple arguments to a Powershell opened with Start-Process

Tags: powershell

So I'm using the command

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runas -ArgumentList $cmds
```

where $cmds is

```
$cmds = "cd C:\", "dir"
```

I just want the new powershell that I'm opening to run multiple commands before it automatically closes.

Comment: I'm not sure of your use case, but I would probably create a script file containing the commands and run that.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart How would the script file help?  I'm not saying it won't, I'm saying I don't understand.  If what I have above won't work, what do I have to do to get it to work?

Comment: This depends on your use case. A scriptblock (like the answer below) may do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `$cmds` to:

`$cmds = {"cd C:\"; "dir";}`

Comment: You are correct sir.  The one problem (which was my mistake) was that you need to escape the \ with another \